# Mouse cursor moves to the start of the sentence

Tags: ubuntu-mate, mouse-scroll

I'm using Ubuntu MATE. Here's a picture of my problem - the random scrolling of webpages when i tried to search for "mouse cursor".

I don't think it's a problem with my mouse, as I unplugged the mouse & the problem still existed. I'm a laptop user. I disabled the touchpad, so it is not a problem with the touchpad either.

Cursor is moving to the front, and mouse is scrolling like crazy.

[image]

Comment: To be honest, the pic shows nothing. Please post the hardware specs or in this case the laptop's model.

Comment: this is a silly question, but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yeah I tried rebooting.. And it is on both on my ubuntu mate and manjaro distro... any ways i have Asus X55C sx078d